# Как сменить аккаунт в мобильном приложении GitHub

Tags: github, mobile

Возможно вопрос глупый, но как поменять аккаунт в мобильном приложении гитхаб? Если зайти в settings и нажать sign out то меня выкидывает на стартовую страницу, после чего я нажимаю Sign In и сразу же оказываюсь на домашней странице, минуя этап логина

Comment: О, пошёл в настройки и увидел что можно выбрать иконку радужного котика =)

Comment: А вы пробовали в браузере разлогиниться?

Comment: только что попробовал - сработало, спасибо.